# TradingView Trading Strategy Backtesting - PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator, back-testing

I'm new to Tradingview and Pinescript. I'm trying to learn how to backtest different strategies and indicator. However, Im stuck with the following.

I would like to backtest the strategy below. Where a long position is opened when the indicator turns green. And the Short position is opened when it turns red.
While closing the previously opened position.

**Strategy**

```
 // STRATEGY
// 
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator [MM]", shorttitle="CTI_MM", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue
tc=ebc?gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
```

**Testing**
I'm trying to use the code below to open and exit the position, but keep getting an error

```
 strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = bfrC == color.green)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = bfrC == color.red)
strategy.close("Long", when = bfrC == color.red)
strategy.close("Short", when = bfrC == color.green)

plotshape(series=bfrC == color.red, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=bfrC == color.green, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

**Error**

I'm getting the following error when I add the testing code to the indicator.

> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.green`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.red`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.red`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.green`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.red`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.red`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.green`;
>
> 5:07:15 PM    Error: Undeclared identifier `color.green`

Thanks in advance for your help!